# Add values in where clause using case is giving error

Tags: sql

I am not good in sql. But I am trying to do some thing like the following

```
    where 1 = 1
    and case 
        when first_criterion = max1 or first_criterion = min1 then 1 else 0
        + 
        when second_criterion = max2 or second_criterion = min2 then 1 else 0
        +
        when third_criterion = max3 or third_criterion = min3 then 1 else 0
    end < 2
    order by arbiter_id;
```

If I just use

```
where 1 = 1
and case 
        when first_criterion = max1 or first_criterion = min1 then 1 else 0
    end < 2
order by arbiter_id;
```

Then it works

How can I add values using the first one ?

Thanks

Comment: You can also use `CASE WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE END` instead of `WHEN ..THEN.. ELSE`

Comment: so you might try this`where ((case when first_criterion = max1 or first_criterion = min1 then 1 else 0 END)
        + 
        (CASE when second_criterion = max2 or second_criterion = min2 then 1 else 0 END)
        +
        (CASE when third_criterion = max3 or third_criterion = min3 then 1 else 0 END))  < 2
order by arbiter_id;`

Comment: It's far better to just write your criteria using and/or logic, using a case expression in the where clause is not sargable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out the rows where more than 1 of the conditions apply then you need 3 separate `CASE` expressions:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND CASE WHEN first_criterion = max1 OR first_criterion = min1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + 
      CASE WHEN second_criterion = max2 OR second_criterion = min2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      +
      CASE WHEN third_criterion = max3 OR third_criterion = min3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      < 2
ORDER BY arbiter_id;
```

If you actually want the rows where exactly 1 of the conditions apply, you should change `< 2` to `= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are making a typo, can you check this:

```
where 1 = 1
and case 
    when first_criterion = max1 or first_criterion = min1 then 1
    when second_criterion = max2 or second_criterion = min2 then 1
    when third_criterion = max3 or third_criterion = min3 then 1 
    else 0
end < 2
order by arbiter_id;
```